# Retroactively have to bring a chatas

Tags: halacha, shabbat, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, korban, machlokes

Suppose one does an act on [shabbas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/shabbat/info) about which there is a [machlokes](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/587) whether it is forbidden [d'oraysia](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/623) or not (perhaps even a [posek](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1428) holds it is permitted). This person does the act regardless, but then he decides to ask his [Rav](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/593) because he knows it is a machlokes and the Rav declares the act an [issur](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/585) d'oraysia. Is this person liable to bring a chatas (sacrificial offering brought on a d'oraysia violation of shabbas)?

Since he now holds it is prohibited, do we say that, every time he did the act before the prohibiting ruling, he did something wrong? Or do we say that, since there are opinions who hold it is not a d'oraysia or even that its permitted, he would be exempt from a chatas up until he asked his Rav?

Comment: Who says that it's mutar to do a malacha on Shabbos?

Comment: no one I meant melacha as something which is debatable not like planting(av melacha) ,or sowing something like electricity which was debated.

Comment: Ah ok. I misunderstood the statement.

Comment: Yes. See beginning of Horyos. Or Shabbos ch. 7. about a Tinok Shenishba

Comment: This won't answer your question but it's very close http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_22.html#HtmpReportNum0093_L2 see 318:1:3,4.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, thanks for source,you are right that it's very close ,the major difference though is that he brings a case where it was discerned that the Ravs psak was incorrect,in my case it is a machlokes between to bekeim in halacha and none are wrong just two different savoras.Take electricity it was a big machlokes ranging from boneh,maver,makeh bpatish,or a minhag.